# why doesn't increasing order of the post no gives sink (node in strongly connected sink component of the corresponding DAG of graph) node in graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Reading about the graphs.. it is said that every graph is the DAG directed acyclic graph of its strongly connected components. Therefore inorder to find these strongly connected components one need to find the node in the sink part of the graph.. now to explain further I need to explain post no and pre no..

pre no :- A preordering is a list of the vertices in the order that they were first visited by the depth-first search algorithm. therefore its corresponding pre no.

Similarly 
post no :- A postordering is a list of the vertices in the order that they were last visited by the algorithm DFS.
its corresponding post no

now the highest post gives source node(true understand)
but why not the increasing order of the post no gives sink part ?

my doubt is :-
why we need to reverse the graph to find sinks thereby finding connected components.
why not in the same graph we run an algo inorder of it increasing post no (as lowest post no reside in sink conected component)..

Why do we need to reverse the graph?

Answer (score 2):

Because the lowest post number can even be in the source SCC. Imagine the source SCC (SCC1) being a ring/loop of 3 nodes, a,b&c, where an edge connects a to another SCC (SCC2) which we don't need to know the details of. a,b,&c have no other edges. If the DFS goes from a to b to c then traverses the edge from a to SCC2. In this case, the lowest postnumber in the graph is that of c, which is clearly a source SCC node and not a sink SCC node.

Comment: Great Insight!!

Comment: So can we assume that if there are no cycles (i.e., in a DAG) this holds true?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because of the charachteristic of strongly connected components. it says that every node of the component has to reach every other node of the component. 
with the first DFS you find all nodes a node can reach. the dfs of the reverse graph gives you all nodes a node can be accessed from.

to find the full component it is important to rely on the timestamps of the first dfs.

there are also other algorithms for finding strongly connected components, which are in my opinion easier to understand. one would be [kosarajus algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm). 
just have a look at it.

hope I got you right and that helped :)